TokenAccountNotFoundError from getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount
Error I'm getting: TokenAccountNotFoundError
It happens at getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount, I had checked other posts with same issue where they had to change commitment to "confirmed", but that didn't seem to work for me.
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bs58 = require('bs58'); // Import bs58 library
const web3 = require('@solana/web3.js');
const splToken = require('@solana/spl-token');
const { createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction, PROGRAM_ID } = require('@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata');

const folderDB = require('@karlito1501/folder-db');
const db = folderDB.init('db');

const configDb = db.createTable('config');


router.get('/create', (req, res) => {
    const config = configDb.read('config');

    res.render('create', {
        wallet_private_key: config.wallet_private_key,
        solana_network: config.solana_network,

    });
})


router.post('/create', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('Starting token creation process...');
    const { tokenDecimals, tokenInitialSupply, tokenName, tokenSymbol, tokenURI } = req.body;


    const config = configDb.read('config');
    const walletPrivateKey = config.wallet_private_key;
    const solanaNetwork = config.solana_network;


    try {
        const connection = new web3.Connection(web3.clusterApiUrl(solanaNetwork), {
            commitment: "confirmed",
        });
        const wallet = web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs58.default.decode(walletPrivateKey));
        const publicKey = wallet.publicKey;

        const MINT_SIZE = splToken.MintLayout.span;
        const TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID = new web3.PublicKey("TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA");
        const METADATA_PROGRAM_ID = new web3.PublicKey("metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s");

        if (!publicKey) {
            throw new Error('Failed to derive public key from wallet.');
        }

        console.log('Deriving minimum balance for rent exempt mint...');
        const lamports = await splToken.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint(connection);
        console.log('Minimum balance for rent exempt mint:', lamports);

        console.log('Generating new mint keypair...');
        const mintKeypair = web3.Keypair.generate();
        console.log('Mint keypair generated:', mintKeypair.publicKey.toBase58());
        
        const tokenATA = await splToken.getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
            connection,
            wallet,
            mintKeypair.publicKey,
            publicKey
        );

        const transaction = new web3.Transaction().add(
            web3.SystemProgram.createAccount({
                fromPubkey: publicKey,
                newAccountPubkey: mintKeypair.publicKey,
                space: MINT_SIZE,
                lamports: lamports,
                programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            })
        );

        await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [wallet, mintKeypair]);

        const initMintTx = new web3.Transaction().add(
            splToken.createInitializeMintInstruction(
                mintKeypair.publicKey,
                tokenDecimals,
                publicKey,
                publicKey,
                TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
            )
        );

        await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, initMintTx, [wallet, mintKeypair]);

        console.log('Associated token account:', tokenATA.address.toBase58());

        console.log('Creating new token transaction...');
        const createNewTokenTransaction = new web3.Transaction().add(
            web3.SystemProgram.createAccount({
                fromPubkey: publicKey,
                newAccountPubkey: mintKeypair.publicKey,
                space: MINT_SIZE,
                lamports: lamports,
                programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            }),
            splToken.createInitializeMintInstruction(
                mintKeypair.publicKey,
                tokenDecimals,
                publicKey,
                publicKey,
                TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
            ),
            splToken.createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
                publicKey,
                tokenATA,
                publicKey,
                mintKeypair.publicKey,
            ),
            splToken.createMintToInstruction(
                mintKeypair.publicKey,
                tokenATA.address,
                publicKey,
            )
        );

        console.log('New token transaction created:', createNewTokenTransaction);



    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error creating token:', error);
        res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            message: 'Failed to create token',
            error: error.message
        });
    }
})

module.exports = router;


This code is trying to create the associated token account on a mint that hasn't been created yet by using getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount. Since your transaction to initialize the mint includes the instruction to create the associated token account, you just need to replace your call of getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount to getAssociatedTokenAddress https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/933ae6c0cba427b6ac342b40fa55da436953ab7d/token/js/src/state/mint.ts#L162C23-L162C48:
        const tokenATA = await splToken.getAssociatedTokenAddress(
            mintKeypair.publicKey,
            wallet
        );

